Taylors theorem from $R^m$ to $R^n$
I am trying to understand the first order taylor approximation for functions of several variables from $R^m$ to $R^n$. But, I can’t find a single source online!
$$f(x) = f(a) + Df(c)(x-a)$$
Here $Df(c)$ is the Jacobian of $f$ at $c$. $c$ is any point in the “line segment” joining $x$ and $a$. This is just the Mean Value Theorem
My question is:

Now if I change $Df(c)$ to be approximated by $Df(a)$, what would be the reminder term? I know what happens for $R^m \rightarrow R$ case but what about $R^m \rightarrow R^n$.

Lastly, is there a source/book that deals with taylor's theorem in $R^m \rightarrow R^n$?

If I were to guess, your general case is just solving the $\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}$ case $n$ times.  There's no reason it should be true simultaneously for the same $c$ chosen along a line segment (heuristically, the 1-dimensional segment doesn't have enough degrees of freedom to find a solution for $n>1$).

The mean value theorem, as you describe it, does not hold with vector valued functions.

What if S is a convex set and $a$ is a unit vector in Thm 1 in MVT for vector valued functions. I feel like I am missing something here, but what exactly is wrong?

@DebojjalBagchi After you fix some vector $b$, then the equation you're dealing with is $$b^Tf(x) = b^Tf(a) + b^TDf(c)(x-a)$$
where $c = c(x,a,b)$ depends on $b$ as well as $x$ and $a$.  This is fine, but you cannot go from this to what you have claimed is the MVT (which doesn't work)
